# How to add convenient buttons for new custom post statuses

Tags: posts, customization, admin, custom-write-panel

I add new post status via this code in functions:

```
function custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'spam', array(
        'label' => _x( 'Spam', 'post' ),
        'public' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'SPAM <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'SPAM <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );
}

function append_post_status_list() {
    global $post;
    $complete = '';
    $label = '';
    if( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        if( $post->post_status == 'spam' ) {
            $complete = ' selected="selected"';
            $label = '<span id="post-status-display">SPAM</span>';
        }

        echo '<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"spam\" '.$complete.'>SPAM</option>");
                $(".misc-pub-section label").append("'.$label.'");
            });
            </script>';
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_status' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'append_post_status_list' );
```

How to add:
 1. Convinient button in post editing page (like Update or Preview) in admin panel
[image]

2. Add "Send to spam" option in post listing in admin panel
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a work tool set that works nice for this kind of add on, called CMB2.  You can add all the fields and buttons you want as part of a metabox series.   Metaboxes are what make up the admin section section of wordpress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmb2/

For example..a snippet:

```
 function custom_post_status() {
          register_post_status( 'spam', array(
         'label' => _x( 'Spam', 'post' ),
         'public' => false,
         'exclude_from_search' => true,
         'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
         'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
         'label_count' => _n_noop( 'SPAM <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 
 'SPAM <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
     ) );
 }



 add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'cmb2_sample_metaboxes' );
 /**
  * Define the metabox and field configurations.
  */
 function cmb2_sample_metaboxes() {

// Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
$prefix = '_yourprefix_';

/**
 * Initiate the metabox
 */
$cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
    'id'            => 'test_metabox',
    'title'         => __( 'Test Metabox', 'cmb2' ),
    'object_types'  => 'spam', '  // <<<==== YOUR POST STATUS NAME
    'context'       => 'normal',
    'priority'      => 'high',
    'show_names'    => true, // Show field names on the left
    // 'cmb_styles' => false, // false to disable the CMB stylesheet
    // 'closed'     => true, // Keep the metabox closed by default
) );

// Regular text field
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name'       => __( 'Test Text', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'         => $prefix . 'text',
    'type'       => 'text',
    'show_on_cb' => 'cmb2_hide_if_no_cats', // function should return a bool value
    // 'sanitization_cb' => 'my_custom_sanitization', // custom sanitization callback parameter
    // 'escape_cb'       => 'my_custom_escaping',  // custom escaping callback parameter
    // 'on_front'        => false, // Optionally designate a field to wp-admin only
    // 'repeatable'      => true,
) );

// URL text field
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => __( 'Website URL', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc' => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'url',
    'type' => 'text_url',
    // 'protocols' => array('http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet'), // Array of allowed protocols
    // 'repeatable' => true,
) );

// Email text field
$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => __( 'Test Text Email', 'cmb2' ),
    'desc' => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
    'id'   => $prefix . 'email',
    'type' => 'text_email',
    // 'repeatable' => true,
) );

// Add other metaboxes as needed
```

}

More can be seen here.
https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage#create-a-metabox